# Using v-model and still loading initial value if available

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child component where I am passing in `customerData`, if available as a prop.  In that component, I have initial data as `customer` objects and add fields on them.  However, if customerData is available and has that key in the object, I'd want to show that as the default value.  How could I do that while still using v-model?

```
 <child-component  :customer-data="customerData" > </child-component>
```

**Child**

```
data: {
     customer: {}
},
props: {
    customerData: {type: Object}
}

<div>
    <input v-model="customer.name" />
    <input v-model="customer.age" />
    <input v-model="customer.address" />
</div>
```

Comment: Since in child component you are defining props as customerData then in parent you need to pass the same i.e., :customerData="customerData" then the data and keys that you pass from parent will be available in child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update `customer` data of the `childcomponent` by the values sent in the `prop`:

```js
const childcomponent = Vue.component('childcomponent', {
  template: '#childcomponent',
  data: () => ({ customer: {} }),
  props: { customer_data: {type: Object} },
  created() {
    this.customer = { ...this.customer, ...this.customer_data };
  }
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({ customer_data: { name:'name', address:'address' } }),
  components: { childcomponent }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="childcomponent">
  <div>
    <input v-model="customer.name" />
    <input v-model="customer.age" />
    <input v-model="customer.address" />
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <childcomponent :customer_data="customer_data" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks!  is there any downside in putting in `mounted()` rather than `created()`?  Also, can I just do `this.customer = .this.customer_data`?

Comment: @HayleeGal58 you're welcome. It's better to prepare the ``data`` before the ``template`` is ready. For the second point, I don't think so, but you can do it in other ways as well, the idea is to overwrite the default value of each attribute in ``customer`` if it's found in the prop ``customer_data``.

Comment: Let me know if you have other questions, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it as the solution to close the question.

Comment: great thanks...I thought `created()` was run before props were received ..I didnt know the component had access to them at that point of the lifecycle